# Resolve a 301 redirect and store the url for future use javascript

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

So I have a script that organises an un-formatted csv file and presents an output.

One of the pieces of data I receive in this data that we must return is a link to an image stored on Google Drive. The problem with this is Google Drive doesn't like to present you with a direct link to a file.

You can get the ID of a file (e.g. abc123DEFz) and view it online at https://drive.google.com/open?id=abc123DEFz. We need a direct link for another service to be able to process the file, not a redirect or some fancy website.

After poking around I discovered that https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=abc123DEFz would redirect you directly to the file, and was what I somehow had to obtain inside the script.

The url it gave me though didn't really seem to have any relation to the ID and I couldn't just go ahead and swap the ID, for each file I would have to resolve this `uc?export` link into this link that would send me directly to the file. (Where the redirect sent me: http://doc-0c-2s-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/32-char-long-alphanumeric-thing/another-32-char-long-alphanumeric-thing/1234567891234/12345678901234567890/12345678901234567890/abc123DEFz?e=view&authuser=0&nonce=abcdefgh12345&user=12345678901234567890&hash=32-char-long-alphanumeric-hash)

No authentication is required to access the file, it is public.

My script works like this:

```js
const csv = require('csv-parser'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    request = require('request');

let final = [],
    spuSet = [];

fs.createReadStream('data.csv')
  .pipe(csv())
  .on('data', (row) => {
     >> data processing stuff, very boring so you don't care
     console.log(`
        I'm now going to save this information and tell you about the row I'm processing 
        so you can see why something went wrong`);
     final.push(`[{"yes":"there is something here"},{"anditinvolves":${thatDataIJustGot}]`);
     spuSet.push(`[{"morethings":123}]`);
  })
  .on('end', () => {
    console.log('CSV file successfully processed');
    console.log(`
    COMPLETED! Check the output below and verify:

        [${String(final).replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, " ")}]

    COMPLETED! Check the output below and verify:

        [${String(spuSet).replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, " ")}]`);

    >> some more boring stuff where I upload the data somewhere and create a file containing said data
  });
```

I tried using requests but it's a function with a callback so using the data outside of the function would be difficult, and wrapping everything inside the function would remove my ability to push to the array.

The url I get from the redirect would be included in the data I am pushing to the array for me to use later on.

I'm pretty bad at explaining crap, if you have any questions please ask.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `webContentLink` [parameter](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource-representations) of the `Get` [API call](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get):

```
var webLink = drive.files.get({
                 fileId: 'fileid',
                 fields: 'webContentLink'
              });
```

This will return the object:

```
{
 "webContentLink": "https://drive.google.com/a/google.com/uc?id=fileId&export=download"
}
```

Then you can use `split()` to remove `&export=download` from the link, as we don't want to download it.

As `fileId`, you can get the Ids of your files by using the [List](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) API Call, and then you can loop through the list array calling the `files.get` from the first step.

My apologies if I misunderstood your issue.

In case you need help with the authentication to the Google Services, you can take a look at the [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/js)

Comment: The problem is that I need to get a link directly to the file and if I cannot then how can I store data to an array inside a function then access the data I stored in the array outside a function?

Comment: I need to get the direct urls of the files or download them somehow

Comment: I tried the code above with a CSV file and it returns the direct link to download the file.

Comment: It takes you to a web page that redirects you, this wouldn't function correctly sadly.